# Counting non-nulls in pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset with ~70 columns that looks like this:

```
ID_number   Meeting1    Meeting2    Meeting3    Meeting4    Meeting5    Comments    …
123456789   9/15/2015   1/8/2016    4/27/2016   NaN         NaN         text text   …
987654321   9/22/2016   NaN         2/25/2017   NaN         NaN         text text   …
456789123   10/1/2015   11/30/2015  NaN         NaN         NaN         text text   …
```

I'd like to create an additional column (meeting_count) that has the count of non null values for the columns Meeting1-Meeting5 for the respective ID_number.

Usually I would use SQL and do something like:

```
select
    Meeting1,
    Meeting2,
    Meeting3,
    Meeting4,
    Meeting5,
    (
        select count(*)
        from (values (Meeting1), (Meeting2), (Meeting3), (Meeting4), (Meeting5)) as v(col)
        where v.col is not null
    ) as meeting_count
from Table
```

But if there's a comparably easy way to do this in Python I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df['meeting_count'] = df.filter(regex=r'^Meeting').notnull().sum(axis=1)
```

Demo:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
           ID_number    Meeting1   Meeting2  Meeting3  Meeting4 Meeting5 Comments
123456789  9/15/2015    1/8/2016  4/27/2016       NaN       NaN     text     text
987654321  9/22/2016         NaN  2/25/2017       NaN       NaN     text     text
456789123  10/1/2015  11/30/2015        NaN       NaN       NaN     text     text

In [9]: df['meeting_count'] = df.filter(regex=r'^Meeting').notnull().sum(axis=1)

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
           ID_number    Meeting1   Meeting2  Meeting3  Meeting4 Meeting5 Comments  meeting_count
123456789  9/15/2015    1/8/2016  4/27/2016       NaN       NaN     text     text              3
987654321  9/22/2016         NaN  2/25/2017       NaN       NaN     text     text              2
456789123  10/1/2015  11/30/2015        NaN       NaN       NaN     text     text              2
```